# How to make Foxit Reader remember last window size and position?

Tags: windows, foxit-reader

I am using Foxit Reader as my PDF viewer and am generally quite content with it, however one annoying thing is that when I start it it always resets its window size and position to what looks like a built-in default - much too small and not even docked to any screen edge. I haven't found anything about this in the preferences; I'd be willing to edit some configuration file where the default window position and size is stored, but I have been unable to find such a file yet.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ctrl +K shortcut to open Preference menu
2. select History on left and check “Restore last view settings when opening”
   [prefe image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGSMj.png)

Comment: I checked it and the setting always was on already, it still reverts the window size and position.